# Custom Theme's "Preview Changes" Doesn't Work for Previously Published Posts

Tags: php, themes

After I've published a post and try to edit it again, clicking the "Preview Changes" button shows the version that was previously saved, not what I've written new in the editor. When a post is a draft, though, it will always show me the changes when I hit the button whether I've saved the draft or not.

After disabling all plugins, all caching, and Cloudflare, I've narrowed down the problem to my actual theme. Even with all my plugins enabled, caching on, and Cloudflare enabled, the "Preview Changes" works with the default Wordpress theme for me. So it's obviously something with my custom theme, not any of those issues.

I was just wondering what in a theme's files allows the "Preview Changes" to work correctly, or what could possibly be interfering with it (specifically for published posts, since it works for me with drafts). I've looked through every thread here regarding this issue, but I've never seen anyone explain how Wordpress actually delivers the previews to you and what could be disrupting that path. I'm not sure what I should look into.

Thank you!